# visual studio, compile with a parameter

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

I have a program that creates a C# class from a text file. The line is:

```
D:\work> gppg /nolines RealCalc.txt > RealCalc.cs
```

Can I say Visual Studio to execute this line whenever I hit build or run because it is very annoying to do that in terminal before each run

PS: The reason for creating C# clas from text file is because I use a lexer and a parser for something like defining my own pogramming language. And gppg transforms a text gramatic into C# code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a [pre-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

Go to the project property pages - in the [Build Events page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s2128d.aspx).